# Python - 3D Plotting, horizontal lines missing and incorrect gradients showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

I am new to 3D surface plots and I am trying to make a 3D plot of temperature as a function of distance and time using the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm    

t = np.arange(0,60,1)
z = np.arange(5,85,5)

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(z, t)
surface=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,T1, linewidth=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
ax.view_init(ax.elev, ax.azim+90)
ax.set_title("Temperature Distribution 1")
ax.set_xlabel('z (cm)')
ax.set_ylabel('Time (min)')
ax.set_zlabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,80, 15))
plt.savefig("3D_1.png",format='png',dpi=1000,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

T1 is 2D data.  This produces the following:

[image: 3D Surface Plot of Temperature]

There is only 1 horizontal line showing at around 60cm, however I would like a horiztonal line every 5cm (data was taken along every 5cm). It seems there is only 2 sections to the plot along the distance axis. The colour gradients are showing in large blocks instead of showing as a function of temperature all along the length.

e.g. for time between 50-60mins from distance 0~40cm, the temperature goes from ~180 to ~20 degrees, but the colour of that block is dark red all the way along it, instead it should start as dark red and reduce down to blue. How do I get the temperature to show the correct gradient along the whole length axis.

Also the temperature legend is in %, instead of the temperature values in degrees, how do I fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason for not providing a [mcve]?

Comment: The data i am importing is from txt files.  I am not sure how to include this or example data.

Comment: In order to reproduce your problem, you do not need your actual data. You can just invent some data e.g. by providing an appropriate function, which calculates values on a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation of `surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) we find

> The `rstride` and `cstride` kwargs set the stride used to sample the input data to generate the graph. If 1k by 1k arrays are passed in, the default values for the strides will result in a 100x100 grid being plotted. Defaults to 10.

Thus, using

```
surface=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,T1, rstride=8, cstride=8)
```

you get

[image]

While using

```
surface=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,T1, rstride=5, cstride=1)
```

you get

[image]

---

This is an example how to create reproducible data for this case:

```
t = np.arange(0,60,1)
z = z=np.arange(5,85,5)
f = lambda z, t, z0, t0, sz, st: 180.*np.exp(-(z-z0)**2/sz**2 -(t-t0)**2/st**2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(z, t)
T1 =f(X,Y,-20.,56, 40.,30.)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly.  Sorry for not providing data, I just didnt know how to create sample data for this problem.

Comment: See edited answer on how one could create some data.

Comment: Thanks again, that will come in handy for the future.